The true and false bound to el-dialog v-model cannot display el-dialog correctly
I tried using: visible sync, but it still didn't solve the problem. When I clicked the button, the dialog box did not appear. But the strange thing is that sometimes when I save the modified code in vscode, it occasionally appears again. When I refresh the browser It disappears when the button is clicked, and the dialog box still does not appear when the button is clicked again, and the problem begins to cycle.
type here
<el-button type="primary" @click="createAccountsPage">添加账单</el-button>
    <el-dialog
      v-model="addAccountsPageVis"
      title="添加账单"
      width="500"
      :before-close="handleClose"
    >
      <addAccounts></addAccounts>
    </el-dialog>


const myAccounts=accountsStore()
    const addAccountsPageVis = myAccounts.addAccountsPageVis; 

    const createAccountsPage = ()=>{
      myAccounts.addAccountsPage()
      console.log(myAccounts.addAccountsPageVis)
    }

import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const accountsStore=defineStore({
    id:'accounts',
    state:()=>({
        addAccountsPageVis:false
    }),

    actions:{
        addAccountsPage(){
            this.addAccountsPageVis=!this.addAccountsPageVis;
        },
    }
})




this won't work
const addAccountsPageVis = myAccounts.addAccountsPageVis; 

use this instead:
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';

const myAccounts = accountsStore()
const { addAccountsPageVis } = storeToRefs(myAccounts);

PS: Some recomendations for you:

please read reactivity fundamentals

replace accountsStore = defineStore({ with useAccountsStore = defineStore({


and then
reaplace const myAccounts=accountsStore() with const accountsStore = useAccountsStore()
